# How can I request a tag to be deleted?

Tags: support, tagging

I was editing tags for a question of mine, and created the tag [cstom](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cstom) by accident (just by confirming the edit -- wanted to tag [custom-bib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-bib) but hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> too quickly). Now I can't seem to find a way to delete it.

Perhaps there should be at least some kind of confirmation when a new tag is created...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from the [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com) FAQ entry: [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/168244)

> Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC every day.
>
> Tags which are misspelled should have the questions under them retagged to the appropriate tag, which will result in its destruction due to having no uses.

Comment: The action of removing tags from the system through community-driven retagging is sometimes referred to a "burninating".

Comment: However, burninating is often accompanied by blacklisting.

Comment: @yo': Blacklisting? Of user(s)?

Comment: No, of tags. By removing a tag from all questions, you don't prevent people from using it again. You have to blacklist it.

Comment: @yo': How do you blacklist a tag? Should I ask here on [meta.tex.se]?

Comment: You do not, mods do :-)